# What is the efficiency difference between using last and last_value query in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently learning query functions in Apache IoTDB, and I found that for querying the latest value of certain time series, seems like `last` and `last_value` can both query the last data.
Is there any difference in query efficiency between `last` and `last_value`?
Will last_value query data by using cached resource? I need to know which one may be faster in the same circumstances, anyone know about this?

I checked the official guide on the official website, but cannot find the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"last_value" does not use cache in Apache IoTDB, but it needs to do aggregation for data stored, which is relatively slow. If you do not need to do any aggregation calculation, you can use "last" to get your results.